Playwright test pass locally but fails on GitLab CI
I've been searching everywhere and found others facing similar issues, but none of the provided solutions have resolved my problem. I'm testing a web text editor with Playwright, and when I run the tests locally using the following script, everything passes successfully:
xvfb-run playwright test --ui --ui-port=8001 --ui-host=0.0.0.0

However, when running the tests in a GitLab CI pipeline, they fail. Here's the relevant portion of my GitLab CI configuration:
image: docker:26.0.2

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "/certs/client"
  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: "1"
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2376"

services:
  - docker:26.0.2-dind

stages:
  - test
  - build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - DEBUG=pw:api docker compose -f docker-compose.test.yaml up --exit-code-from test-runner
    - DEBUG=pw:api docker cp test-runner:/tmp/coverage.xml ./coverage.xml
  coverage: '/TOTAL.*\s+(\d+\%)/'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: ./coverage.xml

e2e:
  stage: test
  script:
    - DEBUG=pw:api docker compose -f docker-compose.e2e.yaml up --exit-code-from test-runner
  coverage: '/TOTAL.*\s+(\d+\%)/'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - playwright-report/
    expire_in: 1 week

Here’s the test file that’s causing the issue:
test('Add a new job', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('/en/profiles/settings/basic/', { waitUntil: 'commit' });

    // Navigate to 'Jobs' and click 'Add job'
    const navBar = page
      .locator('nav > ul[data-testid=desktop_nav_bar] > li')
      .first()
      .locator('ul');
    await navBar.waitFor({ state: 'visible' });

    // Fill in the job title
    await page.locator('#id_title').fill('Backend developer');

    // Add tasks description
    const tasksEditor = page.locator('#id_tasks');
    const tasksBtnsWrapper = tasksEditor.locator('[data-testid=menu_bar]');
    const boldBtn = tasksBtnsWrapper.getByRole('button', { name: 'Bold' });
    await boldBtn.waitFor();
    await boldBtn.click();
    await tasksEditor
      .locator('.tiptap.ProseMirror')
      .fill('Task details for the Backend Developer position');

    // Select all employment types
    const employmentTypesDropdown = page.locator(
      'div#data_id_employment_types'
    );
    await employmentTypesDropdown.click();
    await page.locator('#id_employment_types_select_all_btn').click();
    await employmentTypesDropdown.click();

    // Submit the form
    const createJobButton = page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Create Job' });
    await createJobButton.click();
  });

When running the pipeline, I encounter the following error:
Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.
test-runner        | 
test-runner        | Error: locator.waitFor: Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.
test-runner        | Call log:
test-runner        | - waiting for locator('#id_tasks').locator('[data-testid=menu_bar]').getByRole('button', { name: 'Bold' }) to be visible
test-runner        | 
test-runner        | at /home/user/app/e2e/tests/jobs.spec.ts:33:19

The test works perfectly fine locally, so it seems to be a pipeline-specific issue. I suspect it might be related to rendering or browser behavior differences in the pipeline environment.
What I’ve tried so far:

Increasing the test timeout to see if the issue is just a matter of timing.
Making sure that elements exist before handling any actions, such as a button click().
Ensuring all dependencies are installed and updated in the CI environment.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have suggestions for troubleshooting or fixing this?

From the error message, I can see that there is a button with testid "menu_bar" is not on the DOM, I would suggest you to check if /en/profiles/settings/basic/ can be accessed on gitlab ci.

Actually, I also thought the same, but I was wrong. The button is actually on the DOM when I check it. My concern is that it might be because of the configuration.
